# time printing its output before the command it runs

Tags: shell-script, time

I have a bash script with a line like this:

```
/usr/bin/time rsync -av user@host:/some/remote/path/ /some/nfs/path/
```

Sometimes, the output looks like this:

```
0.03user 0.02system 0:00.21elapsed 26%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4652maxresident)k
0inputs+152outputs (0major+2334minor)pagefaults 0swaps
receiving incremental file list
2019-07-17/
2019-08-01/
2019-08-01/12:17.csv
sent 416 bytes  received 281706 bytes  564244.00 bytes/sec
total size is 820553959  speedup is 2908.51
```

That is, with the output of time *before* the output of rsync! Needless to say, this makes interpretation of the log more annoying that it would otherwise be.

I should add that this script writes all it output to a log file; somewhere near the top, it does:

```
exec >>$LOG_FILE 2>&1
```

So, for both time and rsync, standard output and standard error are the same file descriptor, a handle to a disk file.

I have also tried this script using bash's `time` builtin, and i believe i have seen the same behaviour.

How is this happening? Something to do with stderr vs stdout buffering? Something to do with rsync forking a subprocess which outlives the top-level process?

Moreover, how can i stop this happening?

Comment: Buffering, yes. If you're really looking to parse time's output, why aren't you using its option for saving output to a file (`-o`, IIRC)?

Comment: @muru I don't want to parse time's output.

Comment: Then "interpretation of the log" is just human interpretation?

Comment: @muru Yes, it's just me reading it! And that is much easier if the time output is in a consistent place.

Comment: In that case, consider using that option anyway, and using `cat` on that file after the command completes.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
/usr/bin/time sh -c 'rsync -av user@host:/some/remote/path/ /some/nfs/path/'
```